# What is the difference between dynamically creating a script tag and statically embed a script tag?

Tags: javascript

I know lots of web analytic tools use the following script to create a script tag dyanmically:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://s/s.js';
    document.body.appendChild( s );</script>
```

My Question is if there is a difference if I embed the script statically like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s/s.js"></script>
```

Comment: Javascript is used to embed the tag if say, the file name is dynamic and you want to use javascript to determine how/what file is loaded in.  If you don't need to do either, just do it statically, easier to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do it so that it loads asynchronously, or at least so it is only loaded once the normal JS has loaded and been executed. It avoids making the rendering tree wait for this JS to load so the page is quicker.

Answer (score 1):

When you statically embed a script tag the file is downloaded when the browser passes through the script tag defined in the dom. Further processing of the html doc is stopped till the js file is downloaded which might slow down the page load time and that is why it is suggested to keep your script tags at the end of the dom

But by adding it to the DOM dynamically you ensure that the script file is downloaded only when the javascript is run. Note this code is executed when it is encountered in the DOM and thus having it in the middle of the html file will still block further rendering of the page.