# Dynamically creating a script reference

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to make

```
<script src="24.56.65.98/Scripts/custom/a.js"></script>
```

dynamic so that if I want to change my server I do not have to overwrite all my script tags?

According to the link below

[What is the difference between dynamically creating a script tag and statically embed a script tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368124/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamically-creating-a-script-tag-and-statically)

the DOM will pause executing once the script generation code is encountered. So is that the best way?

Can I use any library for this?

**My script is not local to the server, and I cannot use DNS due to client side problems...**

Comment: Why don't you make a domain name and access ?

Comment: I would say that you should *never* hard code an ip address, as SURESH ATTA says above that's what DNS is *for*.

Comment: can ignore domain and use `src="/Scripts/custom/a.js"`. The leading `/` makes path absolute

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script tag in javascript.

```
var server = '24.56.65.98';

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = server + '/Scripts/custom/a.js';

document.head.appendChild(script);
```

But as mentioned in comments. This probably isn't a good idea anyway. DNS at the network level should handle routing to the correct IP. Additionally, you don't need to specify the domain if the script is local to the server. Just set the src to `/Scripts/custom/a.js`. If the script isn't local you may want to try doing that first- it's faster, more reliable, etc etc.

Comment: My script is not local to the server, and I cannot use DNS due to client side problems

Comment: I know how it is. Have to deal with some crazy requirement by the client. My answer should still solve your problem though.